# Solving a Laplace equations on a square plate Qn 1 (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

What i tried

[image]

Is my initial conditions correct? And how do i proceed from here? COuld anyone explain and give  a clear step by step solution  Thanks

Comment: "Insulated" means that $u_x(0,y)=u_x(\pi,y)=0$.

Comment: Okay but would u show me how to continue from here. Thanks

Comment: Start by doing it over with the correct left and right boundary conditions. Figure out what the appropriate eigenfunctions are. Then come back to see how to deal with the inhomogeneous boundary condition.

Comment: Yup i redid it with the right conditions and got until the expression $h(x)=a_{1}\cosh(n\pi)/y)(x)+a_{2}\sinh(n\pi)/y)(x)$

Comment: So i subsitute the initial conditions $h'(\pi)=0$ next?

Comment: Why is there a $y $ in there?

Comment: I thought that was the general solution?

Comment: Why should there be a $y$ in the definition of $h(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Write down all separable harmonic functions $u(x,y)$. It turns out that there is a four dimensional subspace of such functions for each complex number $\lambda$ (where I measure dimension over $\mathbb{R}$). Accordingly, I will write $u_\lambda(x,y)=X_\lambda(x) Y_\lambda(y)$ (keeping in mind that $X_\lambda$ and $Y_\lambda$ are not uniquely determined by just $\lambda$). You can do this by making $X_\lambda$ the eigenfunctions of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$; $Y_\lambda$ will be eigenfunctions of $\frac{d^2}{dy^2}$ with eigenvalue $-\lambda$. Or you can put the minus sign the other way, it doesn't matter because I'm letting $\lambda$ be an arbitrary complex number. (Note that boundary conditions haven't come into play yet.)
2. Determine $\lambda$ and (nonzero) $X_\lambda$ such that $X_\lambda'(0)=X_\lambda'(\pi)=0$. It will turn out that there is a sequence of such $\lambda$, call them $\lambda_n$.
3. Identify $Y_{\lambda_n}$ such that $Y_{\lambda_n}(0)=0,Y_{\lambda_n}(\pi)=1$. (Note that the $x$ boundary conditions "pinned down" the eigenvalues that we need to use.)
4. Write $f(x)=\sum_n a_n X_{\lambda_n}(x)$.
5. Write down the solution to the problem as $\sum_n a_n X_{\lambda_n}(x) Y_{\lambda_n}(x)$.

Comment: Could u please help me with a step by step solution with this problem. I still dont quite get it. Thanks